# Setting a default value for a new required field in Fluent migration

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to add a new required field in a Fluent migration. Just like this example from the docs:

```swift
database.schema("planets")
    .field("name", .string, .required)
    .update()
```

But when I run `migrate` I get an error saying that column "name" of relation "planets" contains null values.

Is there a way to set the default value for adding a required field to a table with pre-existing records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```swift
database.schema("planets")
    .field("name", .string, .required, .sql(.default("Unknown"))
    .update()
```

Comment: What is I am using MongoDB as my DB? I don't see anything .mongo() FieldConstraint

Comment: Does MongoDB even support migrations since it's NoSQL? I'm not sure on the answer tbh, the Vapor Discord is your best bet